# Tightening a nut in a tight space

Tags: furniture

I have an office chair where the locking mechanism needs tightening. I think the right way to do it is turning this nut, but the problem is that the space is so tight that if I get an adjustable or open-end wrench in I can't turn it. Is there some kind of specialist tool for this kind of job? I think some kind of very thin open-end wrench with a ratchet on the open end could be what I need, but they seem expensive and hard to find.

EDIT: As you can see in the image, it is a very tight fit with an open-ended wrench and there are some metal rods the wrench hits that limits the range of motion even more.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like there's enough room for an open-end wrench to operate. The trick is to flip the wrench 180° with each stroke to change the approach angle of the jaws.

Comment: I agree, but to be clear, not an ADJUSTABLE wrench, you just need the simpler fixed opening type.

Comment: An open-end wrench with different angle offsets at each end will work - my favorite Snap-On ones would do fine...

Comment: @SolarMike, no, not a different offset at each end ... most open end wrenches are angled ... use the same end, but flip the end over

Comment: Possible dup of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/159974/turning-a-hard-to-access-nut/160157

Comment: @jsotola Sorry, have a look: https://shop.snapon.com/product/Ignition%2C-15%C2%B0-60%C2%B0-Offset%2C-mm/10-pc-Metric-15%26deg%3B-60%26deg%3B-Offset-Open-End-Ignition-Wrench-Set-(3.2-11-mm)/DSM810K  and I still use mine.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the reply. I wasn't clear enough initially, but there are also some metal rods going through that limits the range of the wrench.

Comment: I'm with @SolarMike, it looks like where the nut happened to land has made it especially difficult for you. I can see that a normal wrench, when turned, would become trapped as you cannot detach to the left with that brace there. The snapon product he linked should work, if you use the 60° first with the jaws pointing towards the bottom of your pictures.

Comment: But it's situations like this where you end up making your own tools. I'd have taken on old 17mm to the grinder and cut a groove out of the handle and brought the jaws down to a low profile.

Comment: @Aww_Geez and I have a few made special like that eg 9/16" for carb nuts on a v8 etc

Comment: If the nut is not very tight, it looks like you might be able to grab it and turn it with some needle-nose pliers. (not good for the nut as it'll chew up the corners a bit, but this doesn't seem like something you'll need to do often)

Answer (score 2):

I would propose that you go to a pawn shop or thrift store and get an open end wrench.

You could then grind away as much of the sides or the shoulders as you can but still leave enough so that it is structurally sound.  ( *will not bend* )

If you do not have a bench grinder then clamp it to a work bench and use an angle grinder.

OR, try a universal style wrench,

[image]

This kind fits over the nuts and allows you to tighten it in one direction and then rotate it back without having to take it off of the nut. You may need to grind it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your friends if they have a flare nut or line wrench set. If not you may have to buy a set just to have them. They have an open end but instead of just 2 flat sides they have 6 or 12 points so each movement to turn the nut requires a lot less rotation.